# Marcação do Campo ToS do IP no Openflow

Tags: sdn, ipv4

Sou iniciante nisso tudo, então tenho uma dúvida.

Considerando uma aplicação de vídeo chamada **DASH IF** (dash.js) que é executada (emulada) em uma **rede mesh** com características **SDN** (Software Defined Network).

Quero que no pacote seja marcado o campo **ToS** (Type of Service) para que o *switch openflow* na rede, saiba que é um pacote especial e que deverá ser enviado ao controlador.

Como posso fazer essa marcação? Ou seria a implementação disto? É o próprio *switch* quem faz ou deverá ser implementado algo na aplicação?

Agradeço a todos desde já!

Comment: use o iptables do poderoso LINUX

Answer (score 1):

Olá! Tenho pouco conhecimento na área, mas pelo que sei, é o controlador que define toda inteligência do switch. Então se tiver alguma verificação de pacote antes de que ele seja roteado, isso vai ser definido na implementação desse switch no controlador que é desenvolvido em Python.

A marcação de algum pacote no campo **ToS**, faz com que cada pacote seja analisado antes de ser roteado. Creio que seria melhor indicar a origem do pacote, ou porta, ou ip ou etc para que fosse mais eficaz e a partir daí enviar para algum lugar.

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 1):

Tenho pouco conhecimento na área, mas pelo que sei, é o controlador que define toda inteligência do switch. Então se tiver alguma verificação de pacote antes de que ele seja roteado, isso vai ser definido na implementação desse switch no controlador que é desenvolvido em Python.

Nesse caso, ao meu ver e complementando o que o colega lstonon mencionou, a marcação deverá ser realizada pelo primeiro switch que receber esses pacotes. Para isso seria necessária uma regra que identifique a origem do pacote e modifique esse campo. Para que essa regra realize tal modificação, ela deverá receber a **`action = set`**. O único problema é que essa alteração de ToS está disponível apenas na [versão 1.0 do OpenFlow](http://flowgrammable.org/sdn/openflow/actions/#tab_ofp_1_0).

Então pelo que pesquisei, seria algo mais ou menos nesse sentido:

```
add-flow s1(nome do switch) tcp,nw_src=ip.do.servidor,tp_src=porta_origem,actions=set,tos=dash
```

Como não tenho mais um ambiente SDN, não consegui validar se a regra está completa ou não. Acredito que necessitará de ajustes. Mas espero que seja de ajuda.